# Displaying data on html page received from mysql without affecting page design

Tags: html, mysql

I have a `<p>` tag and i want to display data that I am getting from mysql database. If the amount of data is not so large then it display data correctly and have no effect on page design, but if the amount of data is large, then it compromise my all page design. How can i prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can use overflow  auto for scrool ..hidden for not showing

```
<p style="overflow: auto;">youe data  </p>
```

or

```
<p style="overflow: hidden;">youe data  </p>
```